# SWT CTabFolder Check If CTAB Exists

Tags: java, swt, ctabitem

I am trying to create a tab inferface for my application in SWT.
I would like to setup my menu button so that when it is clicked it check to see if a tab is open.
If it is open I want to switch to the tab and if it is not I want to open it.
I have already created a menu item that will create the tab, but I am unsure how to check to see if the tab exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Boolean CtabExists(CTabFolder folder, CTabItem tab) {
    if (tab != null) {
        int intIndex = -1;
        intIndex = folder.indexOf(tab);
        if (intIndex == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int tabItemIndex=tabFolderItem.getSelectionIndex();
if(tabItemIndex!=-1)
  tabFolderItem.setSelection(tabItemIndex);
else
  tabFolderItem.setSelection(value); //keep your required index in the place of value
```

Comment: Okay, I am new to stack overflow, from next time i will do. Thanks for letting me know.